# How to use Ajax in Laravel 9 for store value from a auto-increment counter in real-time?

Tags: javascript, ajax, counter, store, laravel-9

Here my point, i'm creating a auto-increment counter using Javascript on my main page in Laravel 9.

```
    <script>
        var counter = {{ $number}};
        var counterNode = document.getElementById('counter');
        counterNode.innerHTML = counter;
        document.body.appendChild(counterNode);
        
        setInterval(function() {
        counter += 2;
        counterNode.innerHTML = counter;
        }, 1000);
        
    </script>
```

The variable $number comes from my database. I've a migration : "natality" and one entry = this number variable.

My goal is to create a counter as a natality counter for example. But i want to do it without using API of birth in world. I just want to make my own counter.

What i want to do is to store in real time the new value of $number. Because atm when i refresh the page my counter refresh to the $number start value.

Have you got some idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your setInterval

```
setInterval(function() {
    counter += 2;

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('/counter/store') }}",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            counter
        },
        success: function(response) {
            counterNode.innerHTML = counter;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

and inside routes/web.php, add your route to your controller
like that

```
Route::post('/counter/store', [CounterController::class, 'store']);
```

and on the store method in the controller, you can access the counter as `request('counter');`

and make sure that jQuery is installed in your project.

but I think that will send too many requests to the DB, so the alternative solution is to save your counter in **localStorage**
that will be much better for performance.

Comment: interesting, i will test this. But can you tell me more about localStorage? i don't know about this alternative.

Comment: It is a simple way to store client data on his browser similar to sessions, and you can learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: It's store for the client data so it's not the same value for all the user who access the page right? i want a single value which auto-increment and which is the same for anyone opening the page. I think you're first solution is the best. 
I've read somewhere an another solution that i didn't understand, about making a route in web.php with an API fetch and a function, and it's the route which do all the job. Have you knowledge about this ?

Comment: can you share that solution so that I can explain it?
and if my first solution works can you mark it as solved